# Develop TCP client under .net 4 with sync & async features that listens also server initiated notifications

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, tcpclient

I have developed a TCP server by async pattern under .net4 in c# that handles hundreds of TCP connections simultaneously. It has been working without any problems for months, so, I have experiences with async sockets & co. in .net.

Now I have another project: this time I have to develop a TCP client, that connects to a server (one and only server, not more!) via TCP and sends commands to it, get responses and also handles incoming, server initiated notification messages.

Now I am a little bit confused. I am looking for the most efficient way to  implement these features:

- it must send some commands asynchronously and get their response also asynchronously
- some commands should be sent synchronously and get response also synchronously
- it must listen for incoming notification TCP messages. So, these messages are initiated from server side, they don't come as a response for a request

Which do you think the best pattern to implement it? How to listen incoming, server initiated requests, while also handling client initiated requests?

Thanks!

**Request sample:**

```
02/00059/O/60/07656765/2/1/1/50617373776F7264//0100//////61
```

**Response sample:**

```
00/00019/R/60/A//6D
```

**Notification sample:** `00/00114/O/52/0011456046589/01123404543////////////0000/568112131424////3//43424‌1///0//////56312389921/020100///C3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how the server formats the commands that are coming in.  Let's say, for example, they are in the form " ".

The first thing I would do is write a socket class that handles reading data in and raising an event (say, `OnLine`) for each "line" received (this is just an example, I have no idea what kind of format your command and messages are in).

I would then implement a class that has this text-socket as a member, and subscribe to the line received event.  This class would also have a dictionary of delegates that map to the possible commands that can be received from the server, e.g:

```
public class MyClient
{
    private delegate void CommandHandler(string data);
    private TextSocket socket_ = new TextSocket(); // text socket we created

    private Dictionary<string, CommandHandler> cmdMap_ = new Dictionary<string, CommandHandler>();

    public MyClient()
    {
        // Initialise our map full of delegates
        cmdMap_["CMD1"] = (data) => { /* handle this command */ };
        cmdMap_["CMD2"] = (data) => { /* handler for this one */ };

        socket_.OnLineReceived += (line) 
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) // sanity check
            {
                string cmd;
                string data;
                int pos = line.IndexOf(' ');
                if(pos != -1)
                {
                    cmd = line.Substring(0, pos);
                    data = line.Substring(pos + 1);
                }
                else
                    cmd = line;

                if(cmdMap_.ContainsKey(cmd))
                    cmdMap_[cmd](data);
            }
        }; 
    }
}
```

Note, I have used lambdas here, but sure don't need to.

Comment: The protocol operations are ascii text based, in human readable format.

Comment: @Tom, if you can paste some examples I can modify the above code to show a more relevant test-case.

Comment: Request sample: 02/00059/O/60/07656765/2/1/1/50617373776F7264//0100//////61 Response sample: 00/00019/R/60/A//6D Notification sample: 00/00114/O/52/0011456046589/01123404543////////////0000/568112131424////3//434241///0//////56312389921/020100///C3

Comment: And thanks, very kind from you, this patterns seems nice and interesting

Comment: @Tom, I have edited your question to show the samples.  Thought they were human readable? :)

Comment: Hehe :)) Human readable means not bytes and some hex a things :))

Comment: @Tom, am I right in assuming the first digits are some sort of identifier for the rest of the line?

Comment: So, the identifier of the command id O/60;R/60; O/52 The first digits are just some reference numbers (can be 0 to 99), then comes some length property (like 00059). After comes the command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8921/discussion-between-moo-juice-and-tom)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have rewritten my code according to your code and seems promising.